# MySQL Database issue

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

I have unlimited hosting on Network Solutions for my WordPress site.
However, The MySQL database is 300mb, I upgraded to the max size of the MySQL database is 1gb and I have used all of that space.
They do not allow me to purchase more space. I don't know why. But they told me to add a second database. It is a word press site and I don't know how to use 2 different MySQL databases on one WordPress site. I called tech support and they told me I could do this with a plugin. But they wouldn't recommend a plugin. I haven't found one nor any way to access both databases from the same WordPress aplication. Any ideas?

Comment: this is not the solution, but I will recommend you to move your site to anoher shared hosting with unlimited mysql size or even better mve to a VPS :) I don't think 2 databases should be the solution Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have autosave and revisions enabled, so by default wordpress saves your post, pages, meta after every 1 min. These saves are not actually implimented on your current post but they are saved as a revision. So if you stay on the edit page for 10 mins, you will have 10 revisions of the same post.

You can either increase the autosave time in wp-config.php

```
define( 'AUTOSAVE_INTERVAL', 300 ); //5 Mins
```

And reduce the number of revisions to 3, so it will only keep track of the last 3 changes or remove it completly.

```
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', 3 ); // Keep track of last 3 changes
/************** OR ****************/
define( 'WP_POST_REVISIONS', false ); // Remove revision control completely
```

This will only apply to the future posts and pages. To remove the current revisions in your database install a plugin called "Optimize Database after Deleting Revisions", this will remove your current revisions and also optimize the database. Delete this plugin after using it.